# Fetch vs FetchMany in NHibernate Linq provider

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fetch, eager-loading

NHibernate eager loading can be done using `Fetch` and `FetchMany`, as described in [NHibernate Linq Eager Fetching](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html) on Mike Hadlow's blog.

What is the difference between these two methods and under what circumstance would each be used?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`Fetch` should be used for references and `FetchMany` for collections.

This is particularly important because only `FetchMany` can be combined with `ThenFetchMany` to fetch "grandchildren" collections.

Example:

```
session.Query<User>()
       .FetchMany(u => u.Orders)
       .ThenFetchMany(o => o.OrderItems)
```

Comment: Is there a problem using Fetch() on collections if you're not planning on calling ThenFetch() afterwards?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon since both Fetch and FetchMany work, what is the difference?

Comment: @hardywang: the way they can be chained to fetch more levels. Just look at the method signatures.