# Google calendar API Execute() and Fetch() in .Net

Tags: .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

In all the samples of google calendar I am seeing like

```
service.Events.Insert(body,id).Execute()
```

But When I am using the API in my code I am getting like

```
service.Events.Insert(body,id).Fetch()
```

Please help me to get understand what is the difference in these two things.
I am able to Insert the events in google calendar with Fetch method.

and tell me Whether I am using a correct API dlls

Answer (score 1):

You are able to `Insert` the `Event` in Google Calendar by using both methods since you are calling the `Insert` function on both. Notice in the code you provided that `Events.Insert` is included in both.

Regarding the difference of `.Execute()` and `.Fetch()`, I've done a **LOT** of digging, but I wasn't able to find a clear document that describes what it technically does, however I'll just go on ahead and provide the descriptions I found that I think best defines them, based on the sites I've visited. What I think is that both have a relation the execution of a query.

`.Execute()` - a native language capability in .NET ([LINQ - Language Integrated Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)), which is commonly used to execute a query. Got it from this [reference site](https://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/).

`.Fetch()` - similar to `.Execute()`, it executes the provided query and is also used to get references. Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394692/fetch-vs-fetchmany-in-nhibernate-linq-provider) that mentions the difference of `Fetch` vs `FetchMany`.

Hope this gives you an idea on what it does somehow. Good luck.